# Pathway to learning perfectoid spaces.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, book-recommendation, advice

If one has as a starting point the "standard knowledge" of IMO and strong notions in algebra, topology and analysis, and if the end of the road is to reach a high level in algebraic geometry (specialised in ***perfectoid spaces***) to be able to carry out research in the area, which subjects, books, courses , resources , seminars etc. are *recommended* to have a direct and complete path (achieve the desired goal)?

Comment: I mean you know this is the answer you're going to get: if you haven't even learned algebraic geometry/algebraic number theory yet, trying to define a 'road' to learning perfectoid spaces is somewhat ill-advised. I don't just mean that trying to architect such a path is hard, but more that having that goal expressly in mind is missing the forest through the trees a bit. If you're interested in studying number theory, I would suggest getting a strong grounding in algebraic geometry and algebraic number theory first. For this, I would suggest reading the standard texts in these subjects

Comment: Specifically, for algebraic geometry I would recommend Gortz and Wedhorn, Mumford's little red book, and Mumford and Oda's text (see https://www.dam.brown.edu/people/mumford/alg_geom/papers/AGII.pdf). I would recommend first Ireland and Rosen's book A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory. I would then suggest moving to Number Theory I&II by Kazuya Kato and Neukirch's book. Once these are done I would suggest reading books that introduce one to arithmetic geometry in general. For this I suggest Bjorn Poonen's book on rational points (https://math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/Qpoints.pdf)

Comment: and Szamuely's book Galois Groups and Fundamental Groups (although I want to emphasize that Poonen's book is absolutely phenomenal, and should absolutely be your first go-to). Once this is done you will have a fairly broad, but strong foundation in arithmetic geometry. Once that's done then you can reevaluate what you want to do. In fact, before this point I would suggest that you are not really very capable of even evaluating whether perfectoid spaces are something of interest to you at more than a superficial level. I apologize for sounding harsh, but I think this is actually sound advice.

Comment: Perfectoid spaces were the topic of the Arizona Winter School a few years ago. There are resources on their webpage that may help: https://www.math.arizona.edu/~swc/aws/2017/index.html